# tf.estimator shuffle - random seed?

Tags: python, random, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

When I repeatedly run `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` the results are slightly different each time. I'm guessing that's because of the `shuffle=True` here:

```
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
```

Which is fine as far as it goes, but when I try to make it deterministic by seeding the random number generators in both `np` and `tf`:

```
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

The results are still slightly different each time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) sets the **graph-level** seed, but it's not the only source of randomness, because there is also an **operation-level** seed, which needs to be provided for each op.

Unfortunately, [`tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn) does not provide the `seed` argument along with `shuffle` to pass them to the underlying ops ([source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py#L118)). As a result, `_enqueue_data` function always gets the `seed=None`, which will reset any seed you set in advance. By the way, it's interesting to note that many of the underlying feed functions use standard python `random.seed` for shuffle, not tensorflow random (see `_ArrayFeedFn`, `_OrderedDictNumpyFeedFn`, etc).

**Summary**: currently there's no way to guarantee stable execution with `shuffle=True`, at least with the current API. The only option you have is to shuffle the data yourself and pass `shuffle=False`.

Comment: IMHO the first statement is incorrect. When the graph-level seed is set but not the operation-level seed, then the operation id is used as the operation-level seed. The operation id starts at 0 when a graph is created, and it is incremented for each new operation.
So I think what's happening here is that the estimator is creating its own graph, and not setting its random seed. Might need to double-check the source code to be 100% sure.  Any way, my conclusion is the same as yours: shuffle yourself and use shuffle=False.